# Creating objects to be added to a list

Tags: python

When creating objects to be added to a list in Python, we can avoid the `if` statement by changing our `create_object` function to return a list.

Is this a good idea or not? Why?

(assume `create_object` is called in multiple places and is always added to a list)

```
def _create_object(self, data):
  if data:
    return Object(data)

if _create_object(data):
  mylist.append(_create_object(data))
```

or

```
def _create_object(self, data):
  if data:
    return [Object(data)]
  return []

# Now we no longer need the if
mylist += _create_object(data)
```

or (late addition) should we be using exceptions:

```
def _create_object(self, data):
  if data:
    return Object(data)
  raise BadDataException()

try:
  mylist.append(_create_object(data))
except BadDataException:
  pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding an `if` statement is not a useful goal. Occasionally it is the correct means towards a goal, such as making code easier to write or to understand. Thus I think your question is too narrowly focused, or oversimplified. The problem here is that the wrapper function `_create_object` is too simple to merit being its own function, and the complexity outside of it matches that inside.

Let's consider some small transformations of this. First we'll take the `if data` outside of `_create_object`. I do this because I find the current implementation is close to do-what-I-mean. This may have been less true if the conditions were more intricate.

```
def _create_object(data):
    return Object(data)

if data:
    mylist.append(_create_object(data))
```

From there it's pretty obvious that `_create_object` is another spelling of `Object`, and the final transformation is to just remove the wrapper:

```
if data:
    mylist.append(Object(data))
```

Let's take a step further back and assume you're pulling subsequent values of `data` from a list that I'll call `data_source`. You can avoid the kind of `if` statement you had before by writing either a list comprehension (with embedded if), or using `filter`:

```
mylist += [Object(data) for data in data_source if data]
# or
mylist += [Object(data) for data in filter(None, data_source)]
# or, if _create_object's conditions are too complex for this transformation
mylist += [_create_object(data) for data in data_source if _create_object(data)]
# or, two-layers
mylist += filter(None, [_create_object(data) for data in data_source])
```

Note that I don't particularly like the third as it calls `_create_object` twice per item, but the fourth one requires your second wrapper - the one that returns `None`.

As for whether you should be using exceptions, the answer is two-fold. If you're dealing with a large number of false values in `data`, and this is in an inner loop, performance could be a problem. In cases like that, it can make sense to implement the look-before-you-leap semantics of your other examples. However, if `Object` cannot reasonably construct itself from a false `data` parameter, it should itself raise an exception. That way if a given caller doesn't check first, it will result in a clear fixable error.

Comment: Its not quite that simple. There are several parameters like data and several conditions to check. I'd like to have the conditions inside the create_object function to stop me forgetting a check when I'm in a loop.